# MVC 5 - How to avoid data being visible in the address bar on Form Submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It may be a stupid question because when I googled I can't find anybody asking this question. But my requirement is to not to show any values in the querystring. The below url shows Name and Password values in clear text, but I don't want it to show.

> http://localhost:30813/Home/Index/0?Name=test&Password=test

Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public SecureString Password { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

LoginController's view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>@Html.Label("Username:")</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)</div>

    <div>@Html.Label("Password:")</div>
    <div>@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)</div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit"
               class="btn btn-primary"
               value="Login"
               style="line-height:normal!important;" />
    </div>
}
```

LoginController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(User user)
{
    if (IsValidUser(user.Name, user.Password))
    {   
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", user);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Your passing those values to the GET method using `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", user);` - just remove the last parameter (`user`)

Comment: You should be POSTing the data back, which will put it in the body. Either way, if your site isn't HTTPS, you shouldn't be sending passwords in clear text through any means

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish after the `IsValidUser` check is done and the user is a valid user? Shed some more light and then we can provide a better suggestion on what to do. Why do you want to pass `user`?

Comment: I have provided a way for you to use your `user` variable in the `Home` controller's `Index` action method.

Answer (score 2):

You are not very clear on what you want to do. You are also unclear on what you `Index` action method looks like. So I am going to go on what I see in front of me.

When you do this..

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", user);
```

..you are redirecting to an `HTTP GET` action method named `Index` in the `Home` controller. It is unclear to me if this is an empty action method or an action method that needs a `User` instance.

If you do not need a `User` instance then you can just do this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

If you do require a `User` instance and you do not want to pass the values as parameters in the URL, then I suggest you do something like this (it is not my ideal way of doing it):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(User user)
{
     if (IsValidUser(user.Name, user.Password))
     {
          TempData["user"] = user;

          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
     }

     return View();
}
```

And then your `Home` controller's `Index` action method will look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     User user = (User)TempData["user"];

     return View();
}
```

Now you have an instance of your `user` variable and can be used accordingly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you say Index is a parameterless method, he showed the code of LoginController and redirects to HomeController Index...

Comment: No reason to down vote my answer because you cannot see! Look at this GET: `Index()`, do you see any parameters here? There are none, zero parameters specified.

Comment: You are showing the Index action of LoginController(as the code suggested)...The Redirection is to a different controller which code is not present there....And this is already explained as a comment by Stephen, How does your answer solve the problem, it only explains why the data end up there...

Answer (score 0):

As other pointed out, when you pass some data in `GET` requests, that is passed using querystring. So if you don't want to show the user specific data there, you cannot keep the `user` object in the `RedirectToAction()`.

One way you can achieve such functionality is to use `Session` variables:

In `LoginController`:

```
if (IsValidUser(user.Name, user.Password))
{   
    Session.Add("user",user);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
return View();
```

And in `HomeController`,`Index()`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    User user = (User)Session["user"];
    Session.Remove("user");

    //other logics here

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit of a round-about way of doing things? Would it not simply be better to `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")` without the user in there?

Comment: Ok, so in HomeController, how do you plan to get the user data? It has to either Cookie/Session/FormData/Querystring........Querystring he doesn't want, formdata is not possible for GET, so I suggested Session.. @Ortund

Comment: Well yeah, I normally use cookies. Also, you weren't very clear in explaining why you were using the session. You only said that OP could `achieve such functionality` and you did nothing with the session in your code sample to indicate its purpose.

Comment: Aren't session variables old school?

Comment: @BrendanVogt I used to use them a lot, then I learned how to use cookies. Only thing I'm still having trouble with is killing a cookie when the user logs out but I think I have it worked out now.

Comment: @Ortund : yes you are correct about that, and I also believe using session is old school, but looking as the code put up there, I don't see the the use of cookies, so I assumed(which might be wrong) the user is not looking for the login being persistent...So for one time use I don't see session being a issue as it is still commonly used in such purposes

Comment: @SamGhatak if OP was looking for persistent login or not, I think my cookie suggestion and your session suggestion have pretty much got him covered either way so its all good :)

Comment: Yes @Ortund :) now we have the `TempData` as well...going good for @gangt:D

Answer (score 0):

An alternative which I use for more control of my user experience is to post my form data via ajax.

Its a bit more PT but it allows me to interact with the user more in that I can easily show a progress indicator or quickly report an error message:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>@Html.Label("Username:")</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)</div>

    <div>@Html.Label("Password:")</div>
    <div>@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)</div>

    <div>
        <input type="button"
               class="btn btn-primary"
               value="Login"
               style="line-height:normal!important;" />
    </div>
}

<script>
   $('form button').on('click', function() {
        Login();
    });

    function Login() {
        $('#progress').show(); // indicate work is being done

        var Name = $('#Name').val();
        var Password = $('#Password').val();

        var User = { "Name": Name, "Password": Password };

        $.post('/Home/Login', User, function(data) {
            if (!data.IsOk) {
                $('#progress').hide(); // work complete, stop showing progress
                alert(data.Message); // show an error message from the controller
            }
            else {
                location.href = '@Url.Content("~/")';
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is over-simplified. You can do a lot more. As in my case, I'm displaying MDL dialogs that have the error message and titles on them.

The controller looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login(UserViewModel user)
{
    try
    {
        if (IsValid(user))
        {
            generateCookie(user);
            return Json(new { IsOk = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { IsOk = false, Message = "Invalid user credentials" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { IsOk = false, Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Once again, I've over-simplified this so as to give you the gist of it. The Controller handles all of the backend logic and database querying, and the View takes care of presentation.

If the user is valid, the Controller will return a true bool value to the View which will then redirect back to the home page which is catered to show dynamic content.

On a final note, its worth mentioning that MVC comes with built-in login functionality which is probably a lot more secure that writing our own. I'm not exactly sure how to use it though and I have little time available to figure it out but its something you might want to investigate.